# CublasLt cublasLtMatmulAlgoGetHeuristic returns CUBLAS_STATUS_INVALID_VALUE for rows major matrix

Tags: c++, cuda, matrix-multiplication, cublas

I've just finished to refactor my program to use **cublasLt** lib for GEMM and I fell into a **CUBLAS_STATUS_INVALID_VALUE** when executing `cublasLtMatmulAlgoGetHeuristic` in the function below.

**CudaMatrix.cu:product**

```cpp
/**
 * Performs the matrix-matrix multiplication C = A x B
 *
 * @see https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cublas/index.html#cublasLtMatmul
 *
 * @param A - The left matrix A
 * @param B - The right matrix B
 * @param C - The result matrix C
 * @param opA - Operation to perform on matrix A before multiplication (none, transpose or hermitian)
 * @param opB - Operation to perform on matrix B before multiplication (none, transpose or hermitian)
 * @param lightHandle - cublasLt handle
 */
template<typename precision>
void CudaMatrix<precision>::product(const CudaMatrix           &A,
                                    const CudaMatrix           &B,
                                          CudaMatrix           &C,
                                          cublasOperation_t    opA,
                                          cublasOperation_t    opB,
                                          cublasLtHandle_t     lightHandle
) {
    const precision                 zero               = 0,
                                    one                = 1;
    const int                       requestedAlgoCount = 1;
    cudaStream_t                    stream             = nullptr;
    cublasLtMatmulHeuristicResult_t heuristicResult;
    cublasLtMatmulPreference_t      preference;
    cublasLtMatmulDesc_t            computeDesc;
    int                             returnedAlgoCount;

    // Set matrix pre-operation such as transpose if any
    cublasLtCk(cublasLtMatmulDescCreate(&computeDesc, A.cublasLtDataType));
    cublasLtCk(cublasLtMatmulDescSetAttribute(computeDesc, CUBLASLT_MATMUL_DESC_TRANSA, &opA, sizeof(opA)));
    cublasLtCk(cublasLtMatmulDescSetAttribute(computeDesc, CUBLASLT_MATMUL_DESC_TRANSB, &opB, sizeof(opB)));

    // Get the best algorithm to use
    cublasLtCk(cublasLtMatmulPreferenceCreate(&preference));
    cublasLtCk(cublasLtMatmulPreferenceSetAttribute(preference, CUBLASLT_MATMUL_PREF_MAX_WORKSPACE_BYTES,
               &CudaMatrix::matMulWorkspaceSize, sizeof(CudaMatrix::matMulWorkspaceSize)));
    cublasLtCk(cublasLtMatmulAlgoGetHeuristic(lightHandle, computeDesc, A.matrixLayout, B.matrixLayout,
               C.matrixLayout, C.matrixLayout, preference, requestedAlgoCount, &heuristicResult, &returnedAlgoCount));

    std::cout << "returnedAlgoCount = " << returnedAlgoCount << std::endl;

    // Do the multiplication
    cublasLtCk(cublasLtMatmul(lightHandle, computeDesc, &one, A.data, A.matrixLayout, B.data, B.matrixLayout, &zero,
               C.data, C.matrixLayout, C.data, C.matrixLayout, &heuristicResult.algo,
               &CudaMatrix::matMulWorkspace, CudaMatrix::matMulWorkspaceSize, stream));

    // clean up
    cublasLtCk(cublasLtMatmulPreferenceDestroy(preference));
    cublasLtCk(cublasLtMatmulDescDestroy(computeDesc));
}
```

I concatenated a minimal reproducible example below with the same source code as I have in my program (with trims).

This error may be related to a bug I found in [NVIDIA forum](https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/1049211/gpu-accelerated-libraries/where-can-i-find-working-examples-for-the-new-cublaslt-library-/3) but I am not sure.

I'm running on Ubuntu 18.04 with RTX 5000 GPU.

**cublaslt_mat_mul.cu**

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <limits>
#include <vector>
#include <cxxabi.h>
#include <cuda_runtime.h>
#include <cuda_runtime_api.h>
#include <cublasLt.h>

// ****************************************************************************************************************** //
//                                                    ErrorsCheck.cuh                                                 //
// ****************************************************************************************************************** //

static const char* cublasGetErrorEnum(cublasStatus_t error)
{
    switch (error)
    {
        case CUBLAS_STATUS_SUCCESS:
            return "CUBLAS_STATUS_SUCCESS";

        case CUBLAS_STATUS_NOT_INITIALIZED:
            return "CUBLAS_STATUS_NOT_INITIALIZED";

        case CUBLAS_STATUS_ALLOC_FAILED:
            return "CUBLAS_STATUS_ALLOC_FAILED";

        case CUBLAS_STATUS_INVALID_VALUE:
            return "CUBLAS_STATUS_INVALID_VALUE";

        case CUBLAS_STATUS_ARCH_MISMATCH:
            return "CUBLAS_STATUS_ARCH_MISMATCH";

        case CUBLAS_STATUS_MAPPING_ERROR:
            return "CUBLAS_STATUS_MAPPING_ERROR";

        case CUBLAS_STATUS_EXECUTION_FAILED:
            return "CUBLAS_STATUS_EXECUTION_FAILED";

        case CUBLAS_STATUS_INTERNAL_ERROR:
            return "CUBLAS_STATUS_INTERNAL_ERROR";

        case CUBLAS_STATUS_NOT_SUPPORTED:
            return "CUBLAS_STATUS_NOT_SUPPORTED";

        case CUBLAS_STATUS_LICENSE_ERROR:
            return "CUBLAS_STATUS_LICENSE_ERROR";

        default:
            return "<unknown>";
    }
}

inline void cublasLtCheck(cublasStatus_t status, int iLine, const char *szFile) {
    if (status != CUBLAS_STATUS_SUCCESS) {
        std::cerr << "CublasLt error " << cublasGetErrorEnum(status) << " at line " << iLine << " in file "
                  << szFile << std::endl;
    }
}

inline void cudaCheck(cudaError_t status, int iLine, const char *szFile) {
    if (status != cudaSuccess) {
        std::cerr << "CublasLt error " << cudaGetErrorString(status) << " at line " << iLine << " in file "
                  << szFile << std::endl;
    }
}

#define cublasLtCk(call) cublasLtCheck(call, __LINE__, __FILE__)
#define cudaCk(call) cudaCheck(call, __LINE__, __FILE__)

// ****************************************************************************************************************** //
//                                                    CudaMatrix.cuh                                                  //
// ****************************************************************************************************************** //

#define MB 1048576 // 2^19 byte

typedef unsigned int uint;

template <typename precision>
struct CudaMatrix {
    // Matrix multiplication GPU workspace that can be used to improve matrix multiplication computation time
    const static void   *matMulWorkspace;
    const static size_t matMulWorkspaceSize;

    CudaMatrix() : width(0), height(0), data(nullptr), cublasHandle(nullptr), cublasLtHandle(nullptr), matrixLayout(nullptr) { };
    CudaMatrix(uint width, uint height, cublasHandle_t cublasHandle = nullptr, cublasLtHandle_t cublasLtHandle = nullptr,
               cublasLtMatrixLayout_t matrixLayout = nullptr) : width(width), height(height), cublasHandle(cublasHandle),
               cublasLtHandle(cublasLtHandle), matrixLayout(matrixLayout)
    {
        cudaCk(cudaMalloc(&data, bytesSize()));

        if (typeid(precision).hash_code() == typeid(uint).hash_code()) {
            cublasLtDataType = CUDA_R_8U;
        } else if (typeid(precision).hash_code() == typeid(int).hash_code()) {
            cublasLtDataType = CUDA_R_8I;
        } else if (typeid(precision).hash_code() == typeid(float).hash_code()) {
            cublasLtDataType = CUDA_R_32F;
        } else if (typeid(precision).hash_code() == typeid(double).hash_code()) {
            cublasLtDataType = CUDA_R_64F;
        } else {
            throw std::runtime_error("The datatype " + std::string(typeid(precision).name()) + " is not handled in CudaMatrix");
        }

        cublasLtCk(cublasLtMatrixLayoutCreate(&matrixLayout, cublasLtDataType, height, width, width));

        if  (matMulWorkspace == nullptr) {
            cudaCk(cudaMalloc(&matMulWorkspace, matMulWorkspaceSize));
        }
    }

    __device__ __host__ uint size() const { return width * height; }

    static void product(const CudaMatrix &A, const CudaMatrix &B, CudaMatrix &C, cublasOperation_t opA, cublasOperation_t opB, cublasLtHandle_t lightHandle);

    void freeResources() { cudaCk(cudaFree(data)); cublasLtCk(cublasLtMatrixLayoutDestroy(matrixLayout)); }
    uint bytesSize() const { return size() * sizeof(precision); }
    void setValuesFromVector(const std::vector<precision> &vector);
    void setValuesFromVector(const std::vector<std::vector<precision>> &vectors);
    void display(const std::string &name = "", uint x = 0, uint y = 0, uint roiWidth = 0, uint roiHeight = 0) const;
    void product(const CudaMatrix &A) { product(*this, A, *this, CUBLAS_OP_N, CUBLAS_OP_N, cublasLtHandle); }

    precision              *data;
    uint                   width,
                           height;
    cublasHandle_t         cublasHandle;
    cublasLtHandle_t       cublasLtHandle;
    cublasLtMatrixLayout_t matrixLayout;
    cudaDataType_t         cublasLtDataType;
};

template <typename precision> const size_t CudaMatrix<precision>::matMulWorkspaceSize = 500 * MB;
template <typename precision> const void*  CudaMatrix<precision>::matMulWorkspace     = nullptr;

// ****************************************************************************************************************** //
//                                                     CudaMatrix.cu                                                  //
// ****************************************************************************************************************** //

/**
 * Display the matrix
 *
 * @tparam precision - The matrix precision
 *
 * @param name - The matrix name
 */
template <typename precision>
void CudaMatrix<precision>::display(const std::string &name, uint x, uint y, uint roiWidth, uint roiHeight) const
{
    precision *hostValues;

    roiWidth == 0 ? roiWidth = width : roiWidth = roiWidth;
    roiHeight == 0 ? roiHeight = height : roiHeight = roiHeight;

    cudaCk(cudaMallocHost(&hostValues, bytesSize()));
    cudaCk(cudaMemcpy(hostValues, data, bytesSize(), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost));

    std::cout << std::setprecision(std::numeric_limits<precision>::digits10 + 1);

    std::cout << "Matrix " << name << " " << width << " x " << height << " pixels of "
              << abi::__cxa_demangle(typeid(precision).name(), nullptr, nullptr, nullptr)
              << "\n\n";

    for (int i = y; i < y + roiHeight; ++i) {
        std::cout << "{ ";

        for (int j = x; j < x + roiWidth - 1; ++j) {
            std::cout << *(hostValues + i * width + j) << ", ";
        }

        std::cout << *(hostValues + (i + 1) * width - 1) << " }\n";
    }

    std::cout << std::endl;

    cudaCk(cudaFreeHost(hostValues));
}

/**
 * Set the matrix values in device CUDA memory from a host standard 1D vector
 *
 * @tparam precision - The matrix precision
 *
 * @param vector - The values to set the device CUDA memory from
 */
template <typename precision>
void CudaMatrix<precision>::setValuesFromVector(const std::vector<precision> &vector)
{
    cudaCk(cudaMemcpy(data, vector.data(), vector.size() * sizeof(precision), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice));
}

/**
 * Set the matrix values in device CUDA memory from a host standard 2D vector
 *
 * @tparam precision - The matrix precision
 *
 * @param vectors - The values to set the device CUDA memory from
 */
template <typename precision>
void CudaMatrix<precision>::setValuesFromVector(const std::vector<std::vector<precision>> &vectors)
{
    std::vector<precision> buffer;

    buffer.reserve(vectors.size() * vectors[0].size());

    for (const auto &vector : vectors) {
        buffer.insert(buffer.end(), vector.begin(), vector.end());
    }

    setValuesFromVector(buffer);
}

/**
 * Performs the matrix-matrix multiplication C = A x B
 *
 * @see https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cublas/index.html#cublasLtMatmul
 *
 * @param A - The left matrix A
 * @param B - The right matrix B
 * @param C - The result matrix C
 * @param opA - Operation to perform on matrix A before multiplication (none, transpose or hermitian)
 * @param opB - Operation to perform on matrix B before multiplication (none, transpose or hermitian)
 * @param lightHandle - cublasLt handle
 */
template<typename precision>
void CudaMatrix<precision>::product(const CudaMatrix           &A,
                                    const CudaMatrix           &B,
                                          CudaMatrix           &C,
                                          cublasOperation_t    opA,
                                          cublasOperation_t    opB,
                                          cublasLtHandle_t     lightHandle
) {
    const precision                 zero               = 0,
                                    one                = 1;
    const int                       requestedAlgoCount = 1;
    cudaStream_t                    stream             = nullptr;
    cublasLtMatmulHeuristicResult_t heuristicResult;
    cublasLtMatmulPreference_t      preference;
    cublasLtMatmulDesc_t            computeDesc;
    int                             returnedAlgoCount;

    // Set matrix pre-operation such as transpose if any
    cublasLtCk(cublasLtMatmulDescCreate(&computeDesc, A.cublasLtDataType));
    cublasLtCk(cublasLtMatmulDescSetAttribute(computeDesc, CUBLASLT_MATMUL_DESC_TRANSA, &opA, sizeof(opA)));
    cublasLtCk(cublasLtMatmulDescSetAttribute(computeDesc, CUBLASLT_MATMUL_DESC_TRANSB, &opB, sizeof(opB)));

    // Get the best algorithm to use
    cublasLtCk(cublasLtMatmulPreferenceCreate(&preference));
    cublasLtCk(cublasLtMatmulPreferenceSetAttribute(preference, CUBLASLT_MATMUL_PREF_MAX_WORKSPACE_BYTES,
               &CudaMatrix::matMulWorkspaceSize, sizeof(CudaMatrix::matMulWorkspaceSize)));
    cublasLtCk(cublasLtMatmulAlgoGetHeuristic(lightHandle, computeDesc, A.matrixLayout, B.matrixLayout,
               C.matrixLayout, C.matrixLayout, preference, requestedAlgoCount, &heuristicResult, &returnedAlgoCount));

    std::cout << "returnedAlgoCount = " << returnedAlgoCount << std::endl;

    // Do the multiplication
    cublasLtCk(cublasLtMatmul(lightHandle, computeDesc, &one, A.data, A.matrixLayout, B.data, B.matrixLayout, &zero,
               C.data, C.matrixLayout, C.data, C.matrixLayout, &heuristicResult.algo,
               &CudaMatrix::matMulWorkspace, CudaMatrix::matMulWorkspaceSize, stream));

    // clean up
    cublasLtCk(cublasLtMatmulPreferenceDestroy(preference));
    cublasLtCk(cublasLtMatmulDescDestroy(computeDesc));
}

// Forward template declarations
template struct CudaMatrix<double>;
template struct CudaMatrix<float>;
template struct CudaMatrix<int>;
template struct CudaMatrix<uint>;

// ****************************************************************************************************************** //
//                                                        main.cu                                                     //
// ****************************************************************************************************************** //

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    cublasLtHandle_t   cublasLtHandle = nullptr;
    std::vector<float> r1Expect       = { 6, 6, 6, 15, 15, 15, 24, 24, 24 };
    std::vector<float> r2Expect       = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 };

    cublasLtCk(cublasLtCreate(&cublasLtHandle));

    // Declare matrices
    CudaMatrix<float> m1(3, 3);
    CudaMatrix<float> m2(3, 3);
    CudaMatrix<float> m3(3, 3);
    CudaMatrix<float> deviceResult(3, 3);

    // Set device memory values
    m1.setValuesFromVector({ {1, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 1} });
    m2.setValuesFromVector({ {1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}, {7, 8, 9} });
    m3.setValuesFromVector({ {1, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 1} });

    // Test results (just showing it here)
    CudaMatrix<float>::product(m1, m2, deviceResult, CUBLAS_OP_N, CUBLAS_OP_N, cublasLtHandle);

    m1.display("m1");
    m2.display("m2");
    deviceResult.display("m1 X m2");

    CudaMatrix<float>::product(m2, m3, deviceResult, CUBLAS_OP_N, CUBLAS_OP_N, cublasLtHandle);

    m1.display("m2");
    m2.display("m3");
    deviceResult.display("m2 X m3");

    // Clean up
    cublasLtCk(cublasLtDestroy(cublasLtHandle));

    m1.freeResources();
    m2.freeResources();
    m3.freeResources();
    deviceResult.freeResources();

    return 0;
}
```

**CMakeLists.txt**

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10)
project(test-cuda)

# ------------------------------------------------ Compilation options ----------------------------------------------- #

# CUDA 10 does not support C++ 17
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++14")
set(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE Debug) # Release or Debug

# Include CUDA
find_package(CUDA REQUIRED)
set(CUDA_NVCC_FLAGS "${CUDA_NVCC_FLAGS} -arch=sm_75 -std=c++14 --expt-relaxed-constexpr --expt-extended-lambda")

# ----------------------------------------------------- Constants ---------------------------------------------------- #

if (NOT ${CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE} STREQUAL "Release")
    MESSAGE(STATUS "Debug build")
    add_definitions(-DDEBUG_CUDA)
else ()
    MESSAGE(STATUS "Release build")
    set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -O3")
    set(CUDA_NVCC_FLAGS "${CUDA_NVCC_FLAGS} -O3")
endif ()

# ------------------------------------------------- Source code files ------------------------------------------------ #

# All in one
file(GLOB matmul "cublaslt_mat_mul.cu")

# ---------------------------------------------------- Executables --------------------------------------------------- #

cuda_add_executable(matmulTest ${matmul})

# ---------------------------------------------------- Libraries ----------------------------------------------------- #

# Path to local libraries
file(GLOB CUDAlibs "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcuda.so" "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcublas.so" "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcublasLt.so" "/usr/local/cuda/lib64/libcudart.so")
# Link libraries
target_link_libraries(matmulTest ${CUDAlibs})
```

**Output**

```
CublasLt error CUBLAS_STATUS_INVALID_VALUE at line 249 in file /home/rom1/Desktop/test_cuda/cublaslt_mat_mul.cu
returnedAlgoCount = -768202864
CublasLt error CUBLAS_STATUS_INVALID_VALUE at line 256 in file /home/rom1/Desktop/test_cuda/cublaslt_mat_mul.cu
Matrix m1 3 x 3 pixels of float

{ 1, 1, 1 }
{ 1, 1, 1 }
{ 1, 1, 1 }

Matrix m2 3 x 3 pixels of float

{ 1, 2, 3 }
{ 4, 5, 6 }
{ 7, 8, 9 }

Matrix m1 X m2 3 x 3 pixels of float

{ 0, 0, 0 }
{ 0, 0, 0 }
{ 0, 0, 0 }

CublasLt error CUBLAS_STATUS_INVALID_VALUE at line 249 in file /home/rom1/Desktop/test_cuda/cublaslt_mat_mul.cu
returnedAlgoCount = -870514560
CublasLt error CUBLAS_STATUS_INVALID_VALUE at line 256 in file /home/rom1/Desktop/test_cuda/cublaslt_mat_mul.cu
Matrix m2 3 x 3 pixels of float

{ 1, 1, 1 }
{ 1, 1, 1 }
{ 1, 1, 1 }

Matrix m3 3 x 3 pixels of float

{ 1, 0, 0 }
{ 0, 1, 0 }
{ 0, 0, 1 }

Matrix m2 X m3 3 x 3 pixels of float

{ 0, 0, 0 }
{ 0, 0, 0 }
{ 0, 0, 0 }
```

Comment: Ten seconds in the debugger gets me that all the matrixLayout members you pass to the call are null. I'm not going debug 300 lines of code to work out why

Comment: Actually you did :p Setting MatrixLayout with a dedicated function AND setting the workspace size to 0 did the job for square matrix.
Still have issue with non square matrices, I'll dig into that problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did 2 mistakes

The `matrixLayout` was not properly set, I wrote a function to write it before each multiplication based on the `op` applied to the matrix.

Additionally I put the matrix memory **row** major instead of **column** major.

Now the code is working well for square and non square product and row major memory.

**cublaslt_mat_mul.cu**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <limits>
#include <vector>
#include <cxxabi.h>
#include <cuda_runtime.h>
#include <cuda_runtime_api.h>
#include <cublasLt.h>

// ****************************************************************************************************************** //
//                                                    ErrorsCheck.cuh                                                 //
// ****************************************************************************************************************** //

static const char* cublasGetErrorEnum(cublasStatus_t error)
{
    switch (error)
    {
        case CUBLAS_STATUS_SUCCESS:
            return "CUBLAS_STATUS_SUCCESS";

        case CUBLAS_STATUS_NOT_INITIALIZED:
            return "CUBLAS_STATUS_NOT_INITIALIZED";

        case CUBLAS_STATUS_ALLOC_FAILED:
            return "CUBLAS_STATUS_ALLOC_FAILED";

        case CUBLAS_STATUS_INVALID_VALUE:
            return "CUBLAS_STATUS_INVALID_VALUE";

        case CUBLAS_STATUS_ARCH_MISMATCH:
            return "CUBLAS_STATUS_ARCH_MISMATCH";

        case CUBLAS_STATUS_MAPPING_ERROR:
            return "CUBLAS_STATUS_MAPPING_ERROR";

        case CUBLAS_STATUS_EXECUTION_FAILED:
            return "CUBLAS_STATUS_EXECUTION_FAILED";

        case CUBLAS_STATUS_INTERNAL_ERROR:
            return "CUBLAS_STATUS_INTERNAL_ERROR";

        case CUBLAS_STATUS_NOT_SUPPORTED:
            return "CUBLAS_STATUS_NOT_SUPPORTED";

        case CUBLAS_STATUS_LICENSE_ERROR:
            return "CUBLAS_STATUS_LICENSE_ERROR";

        default:
            return "<unknown>";
    }
}

inline void cublasLtCheck(cublasStatus_t status, int iLine, const char *szFile) {
    if (status != CUBLAS_STATUS_SUCCESS) {
        std::cerr << "CublasLt error " << cublasGetErrorEnum(status) << " at line " << iLine << " in file "
                  << szFile << std::endl;
    }
}

inline void cudaCheck(cudaError_t status, int iLine, const char *szFile) {
    if (status != cudaSuccess) {
        std::cerr << "CublasLt error " << cudaGetErrorString(status) << " at line " << iLine << " in file "
                  << szFile << std::endl;
    }
}

#define cublasLtCk(call) cublasLtCheck(call, __LINE__, __FILE__)
#define cudaCk(call) cudaCheck(call, __LINE__, __FILE__)

// ****************************************************************************************************************** //
//                                                    CudaMatrix.cuh                                                  //
// ****************************************************************************************************************** //

#define MB 1048576 // 2^19 byte

typedef unsigned int uint;

template <typename precision>
struct CudaMatrix {
    // Matrix multiplication GPU workspace that can be used to improve matrix multiplication computation time
    const static void   *matMulWorkspace;
    const static size_t matMulWorkspaceSize;

    CudaMatrix() : width(0), height(0), data(nullptr), cublasHandle(nullptr), cublasLtHandle(nullptr), matrixLayout(nullptr) { };
    CudaMatrix(uint width, uint height, cublasHandle_t cublasHandle = nullptr, cublasLtHandle_t cublasLtHandle = nullptr,
               cublasLtMatrixLayout_t matrixLayout = nullptr) : width(width), height(height), cublasHandle(cublasHandle),
               cublasLtHandle(cublasLtHandle), matrixLayout(matrixLayout)
    {
        cudaCk(cudaMalloc(&data, bytesSize()));

        if (typeid(precision).hash_code() == typeid(uint).hash_code()) {
            cublasLtDataType = CUDA_R_8U;
        } else if (typeid(precision).hash_code() == typeid(int).hash_code()) {
            cublasLtDataType = CUDA_R_8I;
        } else if (typeid(precision).hash_code() == typeid(float).hash_code()) {
            cublasLtDataType = CUDA_R_32F;
        } else if (typeid(precision).hash_code() == typeid(double).hash_code()) {
            cublasLtDataType = CUDA_R_64F;
        } else {
            throw std::runtime_error("The datatype " + std::string(typeid(precision).name()) + " is not handled in CudaMatrix");
        }

        if  (matMulWorkspace == nullptr) {
            cudaCk(cudaMalloc(&matMulWorkspace, matMulWorkspaceSize));
        }
    }

    __device__ __host__ uint size() const { return width * height; }

    static void product(CudaMatrix &A, CudaMatrix &B, CudaMatrix &C, cublasOperation_t opA, cublasOperation_t opB, cublasLtHandle_t lightHandle);

    void freeResources() { cudaCk(cudaFree(data)); cublasLtCk(cublasLtMatrixLayoutDestroy(matrixLayout)); }
    void setMatrixLayout(cublasOperation_t op, cublasLtOrder_t matrixOrder = CUBLASLT_ORDER_ROW);
    uint bytesSize() const { return size() * sizeof(precision); }
    void setValuesFromVector(const std::vector<precision> &vector);
    void setValuesFromVector(const std::vector<std::vector<precision>> &vectors);
    void display(const std::string &name = "", uint x = 0, uint y = 0, uint roiWidth = 0, uint roiHeight = 0) const;
    void product(CudaMatrix &A) { product(*this, A, *this, CUBLAS_OP_N, CUBLAS_OP_N, cublasLtHandle); }

    precision              *data;
    uint                   width,
                           height;
    cublasHandle_t         cublasHandle;
    cublasLtHandle_t       cublasLtHandle;
    cublasLtMatrixLayout_t matrixLayout;
    cudaDataType_t         cublasLtDataType;
};

template <typename precision> const size_t CudaMatrix<precision>::matMulWorkspaceSize = 500 * MB;
template <typename precision> const void*  CudaMatrix<precision>::matMulWorkspace     = nullptr;

// ****************************************************************************************************************** //
//                                                     CudaMatrix.cu                                                  //
// ****************************************************************************************************************** //

/**
 * Display the matrix
 *
 * @tparam precision - The matrix precision
 *
 * @param name - The matrix name
 */
template <typename precision>
void CudaMatrix<precision>::display(const std::string &name, uint x, uint y, uint roiWidth, uint roiHeight) const
{
    precision *hostValues;

    roiWidth == 0 ? roiWidth = width : roiWidth = roiWidth;
    roiHeight == 0 ? roiHeight = height : roiHeight = roiHeight;

    cudaCk(cudaMallocHost(&hostValues, bytesSize()));
    cudaCk(cudaMemcpy(hostValues, data, bytesSize(), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost));

    std::cout << std::setprecision(std::numeric_limits<precision>::digits10 + 1);

    std::cout << "Matrix " << name << " " << width << " x " << height << " pixels of "
              << abi::__cxa_demangle(typeid(precision).name(), nullptr, nullptr, nullptr)
              << "\n\n";

    for (int i = y; i < y + roiHeight; ++i) {
        std::cout << "{ ";

        for (int j = x; j < x + roiWidth - 1; ++j) {
            std::cout << *(hostValues + i * width + j) << ", ";
        }

        std::cout << *(hostValues + (i + 1) * width - 1) << " }\n";
    }

    std::cout << std::endl;

    cudaCk(cudaFreeHost(hostValues));
}

/**
 * Set the matrix values in device CUDA memory from a host standard 1D vector
 *
 * @tparam precision - The matrix precision
 *
 * @param vector - The values to set the device CUDA memory from
 */
template <typename precision>
void CudaMatrix<precision>::setValuesFromVector(const std::vector<precision> &vector)
{
    cudaCk(cudaMemcpy(data, vector.data(), vector.size() * sizeof(precision), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice));
}

/**
 * Set the matrix values in device CUDA memory from a host standard 2D vector
 *
 * @tparam precision - The matrix precision
 *
 * @param vectors - The values to set the device CUDA memory from
 */
template <typename precision>
void CudaMatrix<precision>::setValuesFromVector(const std::vector<std::vector<precision>> &vectors)
{
    std::vector<precision> buffer;

    buffer.reserve(vectors.size() * vectors[0].size());

    for (const auto &vector : vectors) {
        buffer.insert(buffer.end(), vector.begin(), vector.end());
    }

    setValuesFromVector(buffer);
}

/**
 * Set the matrix layout before matrix multiplication with row major memory by default
 *
 * @tparam precision - The matrix precision
 *
 * @param op - Operation to perform on matrix before multiplication (none, transpose or hermitian)
 * @param matrixOrder - The matrix memory order (column or row DEFAULT row)
 */
template<typename precision>
void CudaMatrix<precision>:: setMatrixLayout(cublasOperation_t op, cublasLtOrder_t matrixOrder)
{
    const uint m = (op == CUBLAS_OP_N ? height : width),
               n = (op == CUBLAS_OP_N ? width : height);

    cublasLtCk(cublasLtMatrixLayoutCreate(&matrixLayout, cublasLtDataType, m, n, height));
    cublasLtCk(cublasLtMatrixLayoutSetAttribute(matrixLayout, CUBLASLT_MATRIX_LAYOUT_ORDER, &matrixOrder, sizeof(matrixOrder)));
}

/**
 * Performs the matrix-matrix multiplication C = A x B
 *
 * @see https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cublas/index.html#cublasLtMatmul
 *
 * @param A - The left matrix A
 * @param B - The right matrix B
 * @param C - The result matrix C
 * @param opA - Operation to perform on matrix A before multiplication (none, transpose or hermitian)
 * @param opB - Operation to perform on matrix B before multiplication (none, transpose or hermitian)
 * @param lightHandle - cublasLt handle
 */
template<typename precision>
void CudaMatrix<precision>::product(CudaMatrix           &A,
                                    CudaMatrix           &B,
                                    CudaMatrix           &C,
                                    cublasOperation_t    opA,
                                    cublasOperation_t    opB,
                                    cublasLtHandle_t     lightHandle
) {
    const precision                 zero               = 0,
                                    one                = 1;
    const int                       requestedAlgoCount = 1;
    cudaStream_t                    stream             = nullptr;
    cublasLtMatmulHeuristicResult_t heuristicResult;
    cublasLtMatmulPreference_t      preference;
    cublasLtMatmulDesc_t            computeDesc;
    int                             returnedAlgoCount;

    // Set matrix pre-operation such as transpose if any
    cublasLtCk(cublasLtMatmulDescCreate(&computeDesc, A.cublasLtDataType));
    cublasLtCk(cublasLtMatmulDescSetAttribute(computeDesc, CUBLASLT_MATMUL_DESC_TRANSA, &opA, sizeof(opA)));
    cublasLtCk(cublasLtMatmulDescSetAttribute(computeDesc, CUBLASLT_MATMUL_DESC_TRANSB, &opB, sizeof(opB)));

    // Set matrices layout
    A.setMatrixLayout(opA);
    B.setMatrixLayout(opB);
    C.setMatrixLayout(CUBLAS_OP_N);

    // Get the best algorithm to use
    cublasLtCk(cublasLtMatmulPreferenceCreate(&preference));
    cublasLtCk(cublasLtMatmulPreferenceSetAttribute(preference, CUBLASLT_MATMUL_PREF_MAX_WORKSPACE_BYTES,
               &CudaMatrix::matMulWorkspaceSize, sizeof(CudaMatrix::matMulWorkspaceSize)));
    cublasLtCk(cublasLtMatmulAlgoGetHeuristic(lightHandle, computeDesc, A.matrixLayout, B.matrixLayout,
               C.matrixLayout, C.matrixLayout, preference, requestedAlgoCount, &heuristicResult, &returnedAlgoCount));

    // Do the multiplication
    cublasLtCk(cublasLtMatmul(lightHandle, computeDesc, &one, A.data, A.matrixLayout, B.data, B.matrixLayout, &zero,
               C.data, C.matrixLayout, C.data, C.matrixLayout, &heuristicResult.algo,
               &CudaMatrix::matMulWorkspace, CudaMatrix::matMulWorkspaceSize, stream));

    // clean up
    cublasLtCk(cublasLtMatmulPreferenceDestroy(preference));
    cublasLtCk(cublasLtMatmulDescDestroy(computeDesc));
}

// Forward template declarations
template struct CudaMatrix<double>;
template struct CudaMatrix<float>;
template struct CudaMatrix<int>;
template struct CudaMatrix<uint>;

// ****************************************************************************************************************** //
//                                                        main.cu                                                     //
// ****************************************************************************************************************** //

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    cublasLtHandle_t   cublasLtHandle = nullptr;
    std::vector<float> r1Expect       = { 6, 6, 6, 15, 15, 15, 24, 24, 24 };
    std::vector<float> r2Expect       = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 };

    cublasLtCk(cublasLtCreate(&cublasLtHandle));

    // Declare matrices
    CudaMatrix<float> m1(3, 3);
    CudaMatrix<float> m2(3, 3);
    CudaMatrix<float> m3(3, 3);
    CudaMatrix<float> m4(3, 2);
    CudaMatrix<float> m5(2, 3);
    CudaMatrix<float> deviceResult_2_2(2, 2);
    CudaMatrix<float> deviceResult_3_3(3, 3);

    // Set device memory values
    m1.setValuesFromVector({ {1, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 1} });
    m2.setValuesFromVector({ {1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}, {7, 8, 9} });
    m3.setValuesFromVector({ {1, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 1} });
    m4.setValuesFromVector({ {1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6} });
    m5.setValuesFromVector({ {1, 2}, { 3, 4 }, { 5 , 6 } });

    // Test results (just showing it here)
    CudaMatrix<float>::product(m1, m2, deviceResult_3_3, CUBLAS_OP_N, CUBLAS_OP_N, cublasLtHandle);

    deviceResult_3_3.display("m1 X m2");

    CudaMatrix<float>::product(m2, m3, deviceResult_3_3, CUBLAS_OP_N, CUBLAS_OP_N, cublasLtHandle);

    deviceResult_3_3.display("m2 X m3");

    CudaMatrix<float>::product(m4, m5, deviceResult_3_3, CUBLAS_OP_N, CUBLAS_OP_N, cublasLtHandle);

    deviceResult_3_3.display("m4 X m5");

    CudaMatrix<float>::product(m5, m4, deviceResult_2_2, CUBLAS_OP_N, CUBLAS_OP_N, cublasLtHandle);

    deviceResult_2_2.display("m5 X m4");

    // Clean up
    cublasLtCk(cublasLtDestroy(cublasLtHandle));

    m1.freeResources();
    m2.freeResources();
    m3.freeResources();
    deviceResult_2_2.freeResources();
    deviceResult_3_3.freeResources();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please remember to come back and accept this so the question falls off the unanswered queue